# Proof of a false statement. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: group-theory

$\phi:G\to H$ homomorphism (not necessarily onto), $A\lhd H$. Then $\phi^{-1}(A)\lhd G$.

This if part of a theorem in a book, except that $\phi$ is asked to be onto there. The first question is: is the statement true? If $A\lhd H$ then $A\cap \phi(G)\lhd \phi(G)$ by the second isomorphism theorem. And $\phi^{-1}(A)=\phi^{-1}(A)\cap G=\phi^{-1}(A)\cap \phi^{-1}(\phi(G))=\phi^{-1}(A\cap\phi(G))\lhd G$, because $\phi$ is onto $\phi(G)$.

I carefully checked each step. For instance, if $X,Y$ are sets, $B_1,B_2$ subsets of $Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ a function, then $f^{-1}(B_1\cap B_2)=f^{-1}(B_1)\cap f^{-1}(B_2)$. Is there a mistake in the proof above?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: There is no error. You are correct that $A\cap \phi(G)\triangleleft \phi(G)$, and at that point the problem reduces to the statement in your book.

Comment: Thanks Arturo Magidin.

Comment: Use the "fake-proofs" tag for better reception.